# Proper Map for a given function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I'm trying to determine whether the map $f(t) = (e^t+e^{-t},\sin(t))\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is proper. My proof is as follows:

In the plane, compact means closed and bounded. This implies that $e^t+e^{-t}$ and $\sin(t)$ are both bounded if $f(t)$ is a point of a compact set and so $t$ must be bounded on the real line. I'm having trouble proving the preimage of a compact set is closed under this map. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What simple condition will tell you that the preimage of a closed set is closed?

Comment: Continuity of the function $f$?

Comment: There you go. :)